# Matlab: How to publish data report based on a template

Tags: matlab, report

I want to generate an automatically filled-in report, like this

The net open interest of the non-commercials is -21649 contracts, and commercials 20348 contracts.

I used `sprintf`,

```
    sprintf ('The net open interest of the non-commercials is %d contracts, and commercials %d contracts,'..., 
    concise_COT_EUR.net_NonComm(1), concise_COT_EUR.net_Comm(1));
```

However, in the report, it shows

`ans = The net open interest of the non-commercials is -21649 contracts, and
commercials 20348 contracts,`

I don't want the  `ans =`. I have many lines. Each time I tried to automatically fill in something, it gave me `ans =`.
How to get rid of it? 
I guess there must be some other ways to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:**

How about using `fprintf` instead.

```
fprintf('The net open interest of the non-commercials is %d contracts, and commercials %d contracts,\n', concise_COT_EUR.net_NonComm(1), concise_COT_EUR.net_Comm(1))
```

**Second:**

Another method would be wrapping a `disp` around the `sprintf`

```
disp(sprintf('The net open interest of the non-commercials is %d contracts, and commercials %d contracts,', concise_COT_EUR.net_NonComm(1), concise_COT_EUR.net_Comm(1)))
```